# Unable to delete additional ENI attached to EC2 instance through CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using the following template to provision resources:

```
      Resources:
        PrimaryADC:
          Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
          Properties:
            ImageId:  "{{ ami_id }}"
            InstanceType:  "{{ instance_type }}"
            NetworkInterfaces:
              - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
                DeleteOnTermination: true
                Description: "Mgmt interface"
                SubnetId:  "{{ mgmt_subnet_id }}"
                DeviceIndex: 0

        PrimaryADCClientNic:
          Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface'
          Properties:
            Description: "Client interface"
            SubnetId: "{{ client_subnet_id }}"
          DependsOn: PrimaryADC
        PrimaryADCServerNic:
          Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface'
          Properties:
            Description: "Server interface"
            SubnetId: "{{ server_subnet_id }}"
          DependsOn: PrimaryADC
        ClinetNetworkInterfaceAttachment:
          Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment
          Properties:
              DeleteOnTermination: true
              InstanceId:
                Ref: PrimaryADC
              NetworkInterfaceId:
                Ref: PrimaryADCClientNic
              DeviceIndex: 1
        ServerNetworkInterfaceAttachment:
          Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment
          Properties:
              DeleteOnTermination: true
              InstanceId:
                Ref: PrimaryADC
              NetworkInterfaceId:
                Ref: PrimaryADCServerNic
              DeviceIndex: 2
      Outputs:
        instanceid:
          Value: 
            Ref: PrimaryADC
```

When I delete the Stack, it always tries to delete the extra two network interfaces first. This throws an error because they would still be attached to the instance. I have tried giving `DependsOn` for the interfaces but this is not working. How can I ensure that the instance is deleted before trying to delete any of the network interfaces attached (Client and Server).

I am using boto3 to create the stack. And deleting through GUI.

The json file from stack deployment:

```
{
   "Resources":{
      "PrimaryADC":{
         "Properties":{
            "InstanceType":"c5.xlarge",
            "NetworkInterfaces":[
               {
                  "AssociatePublicIpAddress":True,
                  "SubnetId":"**********",
                  "Description":"Mgmt interface",
                  "DeviceIndex":0,
                  "DeleteOnTermination":True
               }
            ],
            "ImageId":"*************"
         },
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::Instance"
      },
      "PrimaryADCServerNic":{
         "Properties":{
            "SubnetId":"******************",
            "Description":"Server interface"
         },
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
         "DependsOn":"PrimaryADC"
      },
      "ServerNetworkInterfaceAttachment":{
         "Properties":{
            "InstanceId":{
               "Ref":"PrimaryADC"
            },
            "NetworkInterfaceId":{
               "Ref":"PrimaryADCServerNic"
            },
            "DeviceIndex":2,
            "DeleteOnTermination":True
         },
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment"
      },
      "ClinetNetworkInterfaceAttachment":{
         "Properties":{
            "InstanceId":{
               "Ref":"PrimaryADC"
            },
            "NetworkInterfaceId":{
               "Ref":"PrimaryADCClientNic"
            },
            "DeviceIndex":1,
            "DeleteOnTermination":True
         },
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment"
      },
      "PrimaryADCClientNic":{
         "Properties":{
            "SubnetId":"*************",
            "Description":"Client interface"
         },
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
         "DependsOn":"PrimaryADC"
      }
   },
   "Outputs":{
      "instanceid":{
         "Value":{
            "Ref":"PrimaryADC"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **tried to replicate** the issue, but it all **works as expected** in my tests. Here is the template I used, as yours is incomplete:

```
Parameters:

  amiid:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2'

  mgmtsubnetid:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  clientsubnetid:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  serversubnetid:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id    

Resources:

  PrimaryADC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId:  !Ref amiid
      InstanceType:  t3.medium
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
          DeleteOnTermination: true
          Description: "Mgmt interface"
          SubnetId:  !Ref mgmtsubnetid
          DeviceIndex: 0

  PrimaryADCClientNic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface'
    Properties:
      Description: "Client interface"
      SubnetId: !Ref clientsubnetid
    DependsOn: PrimaryADC

  PrimaryADCServerNic:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface'
    Properties:
      Description: "Server interface"
      SubnetId: !Ref serversubnetid
    DependsOn: PrimaryADC

  ClinetNetworkInterfaceAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment
    Properties:
        DeleteOnTermination: true
        InstanceId:
          Ref: PrimaryADC
        NetworkInterfaceId:
          Ref: PrimaryADCClientNic
        DeviceIndex: 1

  ServerNetworkInterfaceAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment
    Properties:
        DeleteOnTermination: true
        InstanceId:
          Ref: PrimaryADC
        NetworkInterfaceId:
          Ref: PrimaryADCServerNic
        DeviceIndex: 2
Outputs:
  instanceid:
    Value: 
      Ref: PrimaryADC
```

Comment: Okay that is weird. I will try again and see if I can find a reproducible scenario. Thank you.

Comment: still facing the same issue :(
can you think of something that might be different between our environments? I have put the JSON file that was shown to me from the cloudformation console in the question

Comment: @code_monk_666 Did you try my template that I provided in the answer? It also does not work?

Comment: that worked like a charm...  I will try to figure out what is wrong with my template.  thanks

Comment: @code_monk_666 Glad it worked out. So now you can compare the two, and see what are the issues. But I haven't changed your template except adding parameters to it.

Comment: I think this is because the order of resource declaration is not the same.  if you look at the YAML data and the JSON data the order is not the same there. this might be happening because I am reading the YAML file in JSON format and using that data to pass to boto3 python api.